# PySpark subtract last row from first row in a group

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use window function to partition by ID and have the last row of each group to be subtracted from the first row and create a separate column with the output. What is the cleanest way to achieve that result?

```
ID   col1     
1     1     
1     2     
1     4     
2     1     
2     1     
2     6 
3     5
3     5
3     7
```

Desired output:

```
ID   col1   col2  
1     1      3
1     2      3
1     4      3
2     1      5
2     1      5
2     6      5
3     5      2
3     5      2
3     7      2
```

Comment: "first row" is always smallest value and "last row" is the largest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below

```
  w=Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('col1').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    df.withColumn('out', last('col1').over(w)-first('col1').over(w)).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you’re defining the “first” row as the row with the minimum value of `col1` in the group, and the “last” row as the row with maximum value of `col1` in the group.  To compute them, you can use the `MIN` and `MAX` window functions:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    col1,
    (MAX(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)) - (MIN(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)) AS col2
FROM
    ...
```

If you’re defining “first” and “last” row somehow differently (e.g., in terms of some timestamp), you can use the more general `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` window functions:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    col1,
    (LAST_VALUE(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY col1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))
    -
    (FIRST_VALUE(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY col1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING))
    AS col2
FROM
    ...
```

The two snippets above are equivalent, but the latter is more general: you can specify ordering by a different column and/or you can modify the window specification.

Comment: Thanks, based on your comment I was able to figure out a solution which is pretty much the same as posted above by 'wwnde'.